# Javascript function not firing - body onload

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, onchange, onload

OK, so I have a page that has the following, the function creates a drop down populated with information as q15:

The below code fires when a user selects an option from the drop down q14:

```
onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,'q15')"
```

The same function is called when the page loads using the `onload` option:

```
<body onload="configureDropDownLists('q14','q15');check();">
```

These are the two functions used:

```
function configureDropDownLists(q14,q15) {

        if (langu.languag=='English'){
            var not = new Array('');
            var australia = new Array('Perth','Brisbane','Sydney (Frenchs Forrest)','Sydney (Auburn)','Melbourne','Adelaide','Auckland');
            }

        switch (q14.value) {
            case '':
                document.getElementById(q15).options.length = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < not.length; i++) {
                    createOption(document.getElementById(q15), not[i], not[i]);
                }
                break;
            case '1':
                document.getElementById(q15).options.length = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < australia.length; i++) {
                    createOption(document.getElementById(q15), australia[i], [i+1]);
                }
                break;

        }

    }

    function createOption(ddl, text, value) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = value;
        opt.text = text;

        ddl.options.add(opt);
    }
```

Finally, this messy code is in the `header` section of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.results = ["<?php echo implode ('","', $results); ?>"];

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function selected(){
    var res = 'test';
    document.getElementById("test").value = res;
    alert(res);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var langu = {
        languag : '<?php echo $lang; ?>'
     }
    </script>
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/scriptaculous.shrunk.js" type="text/javascript" charset="ISO-8859-1"></script>
<script src="javascripts/page2_validation.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

The code fires correctly using the `onchange` call when a user selects q14.  In addition, on q14 there is PHP code that auto selects an option if the user has visited the page before - in this instance I want the function to run and create q15 when the page loads, hence I'm trying to use `onload`, however, I simply cannot get it to fire.

Any ideas and suggestions welcomed, please!
H.

Comment: Why do you define `not` and `australia` if English only? The rest of the code will fail if not English. Also not is empty so the first part of the code could have the createOption part removed

Comment: There are about 11 languages - I've shorted the code for ease of reading! :-)

Answer (score 1):

"this" is referring to the select so you need to pass a select object

Do this instead of inline

```
window.onload=function() {
  configureDropDownLists(document.getElementById('q14'),'q15');
  check();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, sadly, no joy. :-(

Comment: Then there is something else afoot like I suggested in my comment.
Please go to jsfiddle.net and set up a real world example with the HTML you use. I will not be around until later, but have some more suggestions for unobtrusively adding your script

Comment: Just as an aside - I'm placing the above in the <head> section, that right?

Comment: Yes - it goes in the head and the onload removed from the body tag

Comment: No go - I'll add the header stuff to the above for reference.

Comment: Show (me) the complete page and I can see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

You have passed a string as q14 when you intended to pass an element.

Having said that, this would be a lot easier to debug if you gave us a jsfiddle.net workspace to tinker with.

Comment: The code is part of a huge page, not sure how to get it into jsfiddle, apologies.